# PHP preg_replace() does not match white spaces and new lines: why?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, pcre

I'm trying to code a script that removes comments from HTML, except those that begin with `[` or `!`. For example, the comments below should be removed:

`<!-- one line comment -->`

`<!--
multiple line comment
-->`

The following should **not** be removed:

`<!-- ! one line comment -->`

`<!--! one line comment -->`

`<!--!
multiple line comment
-->`

`<!-- !
multiple line comment
-->`

`<!--
!multiple line comment
-->`

`<!--[if lt IE 9]>`

I'm trying to run the following:

`$html = preg_replace('/<!--[\s\r\n]*[^![].*-->/Uis', '', $html);`

But it doesn't match the first class of characters (any quantity of spaces and new lines). For example, `<!-- !test -->` is removed from HTML, while `<!--!test -->` is not.

What's wrong?

Comment: Try Regular expression <!--[^>]*-->

Comment: @sam, [`<!--[^>]*-->`](https://regex101.com/r/cL1uL9/1) won't help here.

Comment: I completely agreed @WiktorStribiżew Sorry about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `+` after `<!--[\s\r\n]*` in your pattern :

```
$pattern = '<!--[\s\r\n]*+[^![].*-->';

$string = '<!-- one line comment -->';
var_dump(preg_replace('/' . $pattern . '/Uis', '', $string));

$string = '<!--
multiple line comment
-->';
var_dump(preg_replace('/' . $pattern . '/Uis', '', $string));

$string = '<!-- ! one line comment -->';
var_dump(preg_replace('/' . $pattern . '/Uis', '', $string));

$string = '<!--! one line comment -->';
var_dump(preg_replace('/' . $pattern . '/Uis', '', $string));

$string = '<!--!
multiple line comment
-->';
var_dump(preg_replace('/' . $pattern . '/Uis', '', $string));

$string = '<!-- !
multiple line comment
-->';
var_dump(preg_replace('/' . $pattern . '/Uis', '', $string));

$string = '<!--
!multiple line comment
-->';
var_dump(preg_replace('/' . $pattern . '/Uis', '', $string));

$string = '<!--[if lt IE 9]>';
var_dump(preg_replace('/' . $pattern . '/Uis', '', $string));
```

Output :

```
string '' (length=0)

string '' (length=0)

string '<!-- ! one line comment -->' (length=27)

string '<!--! one line comment -->' (length=26)

string '<!--!

multiple line comment

-->' (length=33)

string '<!-- !

multiple line comment

-->' (length=34)

string '<!--

!multiple line comment

-->' (length=33)

string '<!--[if lt IE 9]>' (length=17)
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked as a charm. Can you give me a brief explanation on why that quantifier is needed?

Comment: `[\s\r\n]*` means "Match [space or carriage return or new line] from 0 to infinite occurences". The problem was that the regex matched some of your comments that shouldn't have been matched because it found no spaces, then a space then `! `. Adding `+` forced the regex to match these whitespaces and then look ahead fot `!`or `[`, as @WiktorStribiżew explained in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that you need to check if `!` is followed with some chars and a newline after.

I suggest

```
'~<!--\s*+(?!!\N*\n).*?-->~s'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jP2zI9/2)

**Details**:

- `<!--` - literal `<!--`
- `\s*+` - zero or more whitespaces, matched possessively so that the subsequent lookahead check was only performed after matching these whitespaces
- `(?!!\N*\n)` - the negative lookahead failing the match if there is a `!`, then 0+ chars other than a newline followed with a newline after `!`
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible, up to the first (*NOTE*: it can be replaced with `[^-]*(?:-(?!->)[^-]*)*` to boost performance, [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jP2zI9/3))
- `-->`  - literal `-->`
- `~s` - a DOTALL modifier, `.` matches any chars.

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/kQO8qi):

```
$re = '~<!--\s*+(?!!\N*\n).*?-->~s'; 
$str = "<!-- one line comment -->\n\n<!--\nmultiple line comment\n-->\n\nThe following should not be removed:\n\n<!-- ! one line comment -->\n\n<!--! one line comment -->\n\n<!--!\nmultiple line comment\n-->\n\n<!-- !\nmultiple line comment\n-->\n\n<!--\n!multiple line comment\n-->\n\n<!--[if lt IE 9]>"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: I'm getting `preg_match(): Compilation failed: PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N, \U, or \u at offset 13`

Comment: Please check what you used and compare with my demo.

Comment: Note you can also use `'~<!--\s*+(?!!.*\n)[^-]*(?:-(?!->)[^-]*)*-->~'`